# как понять когда нужен класс и как написать свой первый класс Python

Tags: python, micropython

Всем привет.

Я Хэнкок, я бухаю.. А не, не так. Мне 35, я хочу стать программистом... Пытаюсь.
В принципе, если у кого-то есть ссылка на толковое объяснение, то на этом можно покончить.

Ещё лучше кусок кода в котором есть класс и без класса задача не решается. Или решается сложно\долго\через костыли.
Проблема в том, что пока-что я нашел чуть больше чем дофига объяснений как делать кошечек собачек и слова инкапсуляция и наследование.

Давайте разбираться вместе.

Если я правильно понимаю, класс нужен в двух случаях. 
1) у нас есть регулярно меняющаяся пачка данных с которой нужно регулярно выполнять конечный список действий.

2) (продолжение/следствие пункта 1) мы прячем(упаковываем) код и упрощаем доступ к нему вместо 10 000 скобок и точек мы такие шлеп, и функцию property...

Дальше. помимо конвенции есть ещё такая штука как правила хорошего тона. Например, если вы сварщик, то нужно зачистить деталь, отбить шлак, убрать брызги, сказать "глаза", перед началом сварки. Если инженер,то подбирать сечения и резьбы не просто из ГоСТов, а те, которые есть у поставщика, а эскизы вынести в отдельный файл из основной сборки ну и так далее.
Полагаю и с классами так же. Может конструкция громоздка, но дает в дальнейшем преимущества при изменении кода.

Теперь пог...кодим.

Есть программа на Micropython. для удобства я? по возможности, уберу специфические куски кода и заменю их принтом.

Наша программа получает данные с датчика (для простоты с одного, но датчиков может быть несколько, и с разными протоколами)
выводит показания на экран
сравнивает данные и искомыми
управляет чем-нибудь
отправляет данные в интернет.

Допустим я буду тестировать программу на разном железе. Чтобы не править каждый раз код, сделаем конфиг файл
config.json

```
{
"ssid": "5G irradiator",
"password": "friday13_666",
"dht22_pin": 18,
"sda_pin": 21,
"scl_pin": 22,
"ds18x20_pin": 17,
"button_up_pin": 14,
"button_down_pin":13,
"relay_pin": 2,
"email": "whatever@gmail.com",
}
```

И тут первый вопрос
Хочу я, для начала к вайфаю подключиться

```
import json

config_values  = json.load(open('config.json'))

print (config_values['ssid'])

print("здесь три строчки кода. на первой инициализируем модуль WIFi \
\n на второй активируем подключение \
 \n на третьей подключаемся к %s" %config_values['ssid'])
```

Зачем больше?

Для удобства и понимания что  происходит на микроконтроллере, запихиваем всё это барахло в отдельную функцию, добавляем пару проверок типа есть ли пароль, завершилось ли подключение. заодно, поскольку, все эти переменные нам больше не понадобятся, их сотрет мусорный коллектор после того как функция отработает.

```
def wifi(ssid):
    print('we are connected to %s, but in 40 string' %ssid)
```

отлично
но на класс пока не тянет.

Однако же. Забегая вперед, я подсмотрел, и даже, со скрипом, понял как работает вот такая штука:

```
import os
import ujson
#тут_ещё_одна_магия_импортируется

#класс содержит данные из конфиг файла и файла ключа (это та самая магия)


class Config:

    Инициализировали класс
    def __init__(self, config_filename, key_filename):
        self.filename = config_filename
        self.values = self.load_config(config_filename)
        self.key = self.load_key(key_filename)

    #это то, что зовется геттером. я так понимаю нужен он,
    # когда мы "инкапсулируем" класс. То есть делаем так, чтобы 
    # переменная values была недоступна для изменения
    #из основного тела программы
    #Но, тогда же по фэншую она должна 
    #называться _values или вообще __values?
    def get(self, name):
        if name in self.values:
            return self.values[name]
        return ''

    # та же песня с сеттером. 
    def set(self, name, value):
        self.values[name] = value

    # и с "в_файло_сохранятором"
    def store(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(ujson.dumps(self.values))

    # вот здесь не понимаю. мы извне обращаемся к методу, 
    #который обращается к атрибуту 
    #который вызывает метод, чтобы создать аргумент
    #я не против, просто не могу представить ситуацию (по неопытности)
    #в которой так будет нужно
    def private_rsa_key(self):
        return self.key

    # здесь у нас проверка существования
    # файла и то, с чего мы начали
    def load_config(self, config_filename):
        if not config_filename in os.listdir():
            print('cannot find ' + config_filename)
            return {}
        with open(config_filename) as f:
            return ujson.load(f)

    # вот тут понятно. мы где-то там в основном теле вызвали функцию
    #передали ей наш класс с этим методом, он там ещё что-то подтянул
    #всё отработало, уничтожено коллектором, память свободна, красота

    def load_key(self, filename):
        if not filename in os.listdir():
            print('cannot find ' + filename)
            return
        with open(filename) as f:
            return PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(f.read())
```

Ладно. идем дальше. 
у нас есть куча пинов(GPIO) и куча датчиков. и каждый датчик может читать информацию по-своему.

Для примера. Прям из учебника (упрощенно, на самом деле).

```
def ds_temp(sens_pin):
    data_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(sens_pin))
    roms = data_sensor.scan()
    data_sensor.convert_temp()
    time.sleep_ms(750)
    current_temp = data_sensor.read_temp(roms[0])
    return current_temp

def dht(dht_pin)
    sens_d = dht.DHT22(machine.Pin(dht_pin))
    sens_d.measure()
    temp = sens_d.temperature()
    hum = sens_d.humidity() 
    return temp, hum
```

по идее эти датчики можно даже на одну ногу повесить(кстати, надо будет попробовать)

так вот. здесь, вроде бы класс прям сам напрашивается.
а вроде бы и с функциями всё работает

ну или вот. 
х - как раз, условно, данные с датчиков. Остальное по выбору стреляющего.

```
x = 6
#the list for display must contain data in format like (string, int, int)
list = [
    ('bad', 0, 0),
        ('good', 10, 10),
            ('ugly', 20, 20),
    ('bullets:', 5, 30), (str(x), 70, 30),
            ('money', 20, 40)
    ]

def display(list):
    i2c = I2C(-1, scl=Pin(22), sda=Pin(21))

    #тут две строчки можно убрать
    oled_width = 128
    oled_height = 64
    oled = ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(oled_width, oled_height, i2c)


    oled.fill(0)
    for i in list:
        oled.text(*i)
        oled.show()
```

вот хочу в класс это дело запихать. для тренировки хотя бы.

list где лучше держать? внутри класса в **init** или основном теле и каждый раз оттуда дергать значения специальным методом, который будет ещё и проверять данные чтоб в нужном формате были?

P.S. скорее всего я неправильные вопросы гуглу задавал. Но подавляющее большинство того, что я встретил 
"Я тут пишу класс чтоб а и б складывать и про функцию lambda я не знаю"
Кого посмотреть, где почитать, можно на англицком. ну даже просто "кусок кода: разбирайся".
желательно ещё и с декораторами.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для конфига на micropython класс вообще не нужен - достаточно модуля умеющего работать с json, тупо захардкодить чтение из json и запись в него. Если есть несколько устройств, которые вы подключаете к плате, и вы хотите работать с ними как с объектами, каждый из которых будет представлять соответствующее устройство, то имеет смысл реализовать через классы.

Comment: Вообще объект - это некая сущность, которая должна представлять объект вашей предметной области. Если вам нужно просто выводить несколько строк на экран, то вам не нужен класс - нужен просто цикл по списку строк. Каждая строка в этом случае это и есть объект. Если же вы хотите реализовать например меню с перемещением по пунктам меню, то возможно имеет реализовать объект-меню.

Answer (score 1):

Класс нужен там, где вам удобно. Питон позволаяет вам их не писать, если не хотите.

В питоне невозможно точно скрыть переменную, обычно просто добавляют __ в начало и __ в конец. Но при этом она в любом случае будет доступна к обращению.

Дело каждого, но на питоне я геттером и сеттеров не пишу и живу спокойно. Обращаясь к [дзену питона](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Simple is better than complex.

А по обучению можно всегда почтать книги, которые еть в открытом доступе, например, "Learning Python" Марка Лутца

Ну или видео объяснения, их в ютубе полно

Comment: Поясню еще раз.  Зачем/в каких ситуациях целесообразно/необходимо использовать инструмент класс. Почитаю Лутца,может именно у него про классы написано,а на видео,будьте любезны ссылку, где класс работает в программе,где он нужен, а не котики,машинки и прочая хрень

Answer (score 1):

"Колея это только моя, выбирайтесь своей колеёй..."

Начните отсюда:

[Python. Уровень 2. ООП 1/10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUpdmr-mdO4&t)

Под конец немного скомканно, но в целом хорошо понятен принцип. И про геттереы сеттеры тоже есть.

Дальше Марк Лутц "Изучаем Python 5е издание, том 2й. Начинается как раз с классов.

Теперь для деревянных, вроде меня.

Если вы запустите вот это:

```
class Config:
    def __init__(xxx, name_outside, pay_outside = 0):
        xxx.name_in_class = name_outside
        xxx.pay_in_class = pay_outside

    def class_mission (xxx):
        print("from class  %s take %s" %(xxx, xxx.name_in_class))

    def bad_for_ya (xxx):
        print("just %s" %xxx.pay_in_class)

c = Config("Pasha")
vas_vas = Config("Vasya")
a = Config("Bad_boy")

c.class_mission()
print("---------")

vas_vas.class_mission()
print("---------")

a.bad_for_ya()
```

Вы получите вот это:

```
from class <__main__.Config object at 0x00A49148> take Pasha
---------
from class <__main__.Config object at 0x00A49268> take Vasya
---------
just 0
```

Что же это значит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обязательно нужна ссылка на авторитетный источник. Как пишет Марк Лутц : "классы в действительности представляют собой лишь незначительное структурное расширение"

Вообще класс, это как коробка с инструментами.
Вы можете пользоваться каждым по-отдельности, но когда там слишком всего много, то пусть оно там само что-то делает. Это инкапсуляция. Понятно?

Напишем функцию:

```
фукнц бить_по_пальцам_за_бессодержательные_ответы_на_форумах():

    Взять молоток, шарахнуть по пальцу.
```

Но потом вы задумываетесь. Ведь для начала неплохо бы проверить сообщение, которое написал пользователь.

```
функц проверить_ответ_на_полезность(сообщение_пользователя):

    if not сообщение_пользователя несет в себе информацию отвечающую на вопрос:
        return false
```

А как, вообще, проверять на полезность, спросите себя вы?

А моё суждение оно объективное?

Если мы уберем сообщение пользователя, о том, что на ютубе полно видео ответ останется полным? да. А если про Марка Луца? нет.

Тогда давайте добавим систему кармы...

И простое битьё по пальцам обрастает кучей методов...

Тут заказчики пришли. Ребята, у вас хорошая система кармы, но мы хотим прижигать утюгом. Перепишите, пожалуйста...

И тогда вы запихиваете все свои отдельные функции в класс. Коробку в которой есть окошко куда пользователь засовывает руку с сообщением на бумажке, и несколько окошек на выход, из которых нам возвращается что? Правильно, читайте (и пишите) описание класса.

класс - это просто инструкция по которой будет работать список других инструкций. 
Вася забивает гвоздь, коля красит.
класс определяет кто кому передает гвоздь, и в какой последовательности выполняется работа. То есть, забивается крашенный, или красится забитый.

Теперь про наш класс конфиг. 
self в начале, это просто переменная. Как видите, я заменил её на ххх и меня до сих пор не поразила молния. (только для наглядности, на самом деле)
Если вы напишите класс и нигде к нему не обратитесь, то это просто набор байтов, лежащих мертвым грузом.

Но чтобы обратиться к нему, вы пишете чё_то_там = Config. 
И вот тогда в памяти появляется запись "вот тут список инструкций к которому будут обращаться по имени чё_то_там"

По факту ххх(он же self) это - просто синтаксис. Если там можно написать что угодно и это надо писать везде, то почему бы вообще это не писать? Потому что, читаемость кода и путаница с переменными.

теперь как же написать свой первый класс.

то над чем я долго тупил, это где надо внутри класса переменные писать, а где нет.

Этот блок только для микропитона (и это мой первый класс)

```
import network
import time

class Wifi:

    def __init__ (self, ssid, password):
        self.ssid = ssid
        self.password = password

    def connect(self):
        print("connect to %s ?" % self.ssid)
        net_var = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
        net_var.active(True)
        net_var.connect(self.ssid, self.password)
             #def check(self)
        for i in range(10):
            if not net_var.isconnected():
                print ('connecting')
                time.sleep(2)

        if net_var.isconnected():
            print("Oh my Lord! it did happen")

pussycat = Wifi('5G irradiator', 'friday13_666')
pussycat.connect()
```

А этот можно запустить в обычном питоне. Только вам понадобится файл config.json из вопроса) (и это я взял из открытых источников и неделю разбирал на запчасти)

```
import os
import json

class Jsonconfig:
    def __init__(self, config_filename):
            self.values = self.load_config(config_filename)

    def get(self, name):
        if name in self.values:
            return self.values[name]

    def load_config(self, config_filename):
        if not config_filename in os.listdir():
            print('cannot find ' + config_filename)
            return {}

        with open(config_filename) as f:
            return json.load(f)
        return ''

#по идее эта запись самая экономичная и не занимает память
print(Jsonconfig('config.json').get('ssid'))
#но, согласитесь, неудобно_")

print("_______")
#здесь просто чтоб понимать как всё работает
mouse = Jsonconfig('config.json')
wifi_name = mouse.get('ssid')
print(wifi_name)

print("_______")
#а поффакту вы один раз определяете объект
mouse = Jsonconfig('config.json')
#а потом просто вызываете его вместе с каким-то методом
print(mouse.get('ssid'))
```

Я так долго скрипел мозгами чтобы всё это понять... аж жаба давит. Ладно, если это сообщение наберет 20 лайков, запишу видос.

Первый кусок кода.

на самом деле тут класс не нужен. мы подключаем вайфай модуль и забываем про него. достаточно функии. в нашем же случае останется объект pussycat, в котором ничего не будет, но он будет существовать. А это не гуд. но джаст фор тренировка.

У Лутца, кстати, объяснено, что import'ы не стоит внутрь класса запихивать. Вообще класс, скорее всего, у вас будет лежать в отдельном файле. Или несколько классов там могут вместе тусить.

Так вот.

```
pussycat = Wifi('5G irradiator', 'friday13_666')
```

Мы записываем в память набор инструкций, по адресу pussycat, и к этим инструкциям приписка, что айди "5g irradiator" а пароль "friday13_666". Это отработала функция **init**. Инит - это тоже функция, ни больше ни меньше. Да, служебная, да узкоспециализированная, но и только.

```
pussycat.connect()
```

поехали.

принт пропускаю, это так, для красоты

```
net_var = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
```

откуда, мать твою, у тебя взялася net_var?!!

Ниоткуда. я определяю ее здесь внутри этой функции и здесь же она и умрет. 
а теперь что у нас справа от "="? network.WLAN() мы вызываем какой-то класс network (который мы импортировали вначале) и у которого внутри есть метод WLAN. А в качестве значения, которое будет подставлено в WLAN, ещё раз вызываем этот же класс network но уже с методом(функцией) STA_IF (station_interface), которая что-то делает и результат этого действия становится значением для WLAN.

нипаняяятнааа.

Ладно, щас к этому вернемся.

Обратите внимание, что в строчке

```
net_var.connect(self.ssid, self.password)
```

мы передаем две переменные, хотя в

```
def connect(self):
```

у нас только одна.

Это self или ххх значит "п..дуй в начало коробки, там всё написано"

моей первой ошибкой было то, что я пытался что-то ещё дописать в скобках. Хотя всё что нам нужно уже есть в нашем классе.

Теперь ко второму куску кода. 
Я специально расписал все переменные с разными названиями и если вы внимательно посмотрите, вы поймете порядок как это работает. Мне оно досталось в сокращенном виде. 
На самом деле я уже подустал))

откуда берется 'name'? это локальная переменная которая появляется только когда вызывается метод get и имя, которое передается get'у и становится name. а потом уничтожается. Соответственно если в вашем словаре был ключ с таким именем, то функция вернет значение которое было под этим ключом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скрипите, спрашивайте, голосуйте))

P.S. 
- А как понять, когда нужно писать класс?

- Очень просто: если можете не писать, не пишите.